# why does the microcontroller pin driving optocoupler is giving 2V even if it is set?

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator, triac

I have interfaced pin 1^1 of [Atmel AT89S51](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2487.pdf) to optocoupler [MOC3041](http://exa.unne.edu.ar/ingenieria/sysistemas/public_html/Archi_pdf/HojaDatos/Optoelectronica/moc3041.pdf) IC, I set this pin to logic high.

I have connected 220 ohm resistor and red led and then pin 1 of the optocoupler and after that Triac is connected. Relevant section of schematic:

[image: Schematic] ([Complete schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUyao.png))

I am getting 2V on P1^1, and when I disconnect optocoupler connection then i am getting 5V. I don't understand why this is happening and where I went wrong?

Comment: A circuit diagram would help.

Comment: That micro shows a 2.4V min output at only 60uA on port 1 if I'm reading it right. I removed my comment about the MOC3043 being a possibility, if I'm reading the datasheet correctly you'll need a transistor buffer.

Comment: Why does it seem like OP has both a Red Led AND the optocoupler's input led in series?

Comment: It looks like you've tried to add a schematic and broken the datasheet links, if you want to post a link in a comment someone can edit it in.

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding how links work, it would be good to review the site help. Your edit has not only failed to add the image you were apparently attempting to incorporate, but also broken the links I had added because you hadn't, as PeterJ has pointed out. Please roll-back your edit so that the question is at least in the state it was in, with valid datasheet links.

Answer (score 1):

The input side of an optocoupler is essentially an LED (or sometimes two LEDs arranged in anti-parallel). Consider this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIHbZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, depending on how much output current the microcontroller can provide on an output pin, or conversely what the output impedance of the output pin is, the load (i.e. the LED in this case) will pull down the output voltage of the microcontroller pin, with the difference being dissipated as heat in the internal output impedance or current limiting mechanism of the microcontroller.

The MOC3041 datasheet indicates the input LED has a forward voltage of 1.3 Volts (typical), and can be operated at up to 60 mA current. Thus, if the microcontroller output pin voltage is found to be dropping down to 2 Volts, the 220 Ohm resistor is dropping the remaining `2.0 - 1.3 = 0.7 Volts`. This would happen at a current of ~3.2 mA, not quite suitable for turning on the optocoupler's output.

This also indicates that the microcontroller apparently has nearly a 1 kOhm output impedance on the pin concerned, to be dropping 3 Volts on a 3.2 mA load: That seems rather high / unlikely, so it is possible that there is some additional load on the output pin. A schematic would help figure it out.

Any which way, no microcontroller output pin will have a fixed 5 Volt output independent of load current. An output voltage drop is expected, the magnitude being driven by the current drawn from the output pin.

Comment: I can't post the image here because of reputation error, So can you please send me your mail-id so that I can send you the circuit diagram for your reference.

Comment: @user27300 Please upload the image to any public image hosting side, such as imgur.com or flickr.com, and then post the link as a comment. I, or someone else with edit rights, will incorporate your image into the question.

Comment: @user27300 Incorporated in your question.